# Huffman Coding: handling negative ambiguity with zero

Tags: binary, negative-number, huffman-code

I've written a simple text file compressor that uses Huffman coding. I encode the text and write the binary resulting from Huffman to a file. To decode, I read in the binary and step through the Huffman tree.

That part is straightforward. The problem arises with 0 and negative numbers. For practice/fun/learning, I decided to do my own binary conversion methods (from a Java byte to a string and vice-versa) and I decided to represent negative numbers by flipping the last bit to a 1.

E.g, `-2 = 00000101;`; `2 = 00000100` (the extra 0's for padding since even the unnecessary 0's are important in Huffman... it's irrelevant, though)

However, `0 = 00000000 = 00000001`

This may not seem like a problem, but those two binary strings map to two different characters in the huffman tree.

Is there a better way handle negatives in binary that will get around this?

Comment: If anyone would like to see the code: https://github.com/thomas4g/huffman-coding

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will help you, but i will try:

First of all, there is different kind of binary, pure or the others. Binary pure DON'T allow negatives, it goes from 0.......

You can use magnitude and sign, another kind of binnary, it allows negative numbers, and the - or + sign is represented with the most important bit of the number, for example:
A number with 4 bits:

0100=2

1100=-2

(1 bit for the sign, the most important, the first left one, and the other 3 for the number)

You can use too the Two's complement, but it's harder and you need to get the number in binary and then translate it to the other type.

I hope i could help you, and sorry for the lot of mistakes in english!

Comment: The problem is, to write this to a file I'm writing byte-by-byte. A byte is 8 bits. So I need to grab 8 bit binary chunks at a time from the encoded huffman string. A byte in Java holds -128 to 127, so I'm basically forced to handle negatives. However, I suppose just moving the sign bit to the front might work, though i was having trouble with that before. I'll try it.

Comment: So while the sign bit at the front does make more sense, it doesn't fix the problem: `10000000 = 0 = 00000000`, and the problem remains.